# Extracting the actual in-text title from a PDF

Tags: pdf, extract, title

There seems to be a lot of questions about extracting a title from a PDF (using its metadata). However, the large majority of the titles do not seem to exist in the metadata. I found this out when using [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) .

Is there anyway to actually retrieve the in text title from a pdf? I tried to export to a text file then search but there is no consistent formatting. Is there any way to export the pdf to a document with its formatting, then check for a font size >= 14 ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33868220/15485

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question.  Applications that create PDFs don't seem to do anything useful with the available metadata fields.

Take *pdflatex* as an example: even when one sets the *\title{...}* and *\author{...}* in the preamble, this information is not reflected in the metadata.  After a quick search, the solution appears to be to introduce a block in the preamble which is read only by *pdflatex* [1]:

```
\pdfinfo
{
  /Title{...}
  /Author{...}
  ...
}
```

...which is then placed in the the relevant metadata fields of the PDF.  It is strange that this is necessary, though.

I cannot speak for word processors like Word or Writer.  One presumes such metadata fields have to be set manually by the user.

Perhaps a heuristic approach is the only way you can approach your problem if your PDFs are not generated by you.  [2] seems like it does something similar to what you want, but I guess it depends how well published the PDFs are -- this tool seems to be scientific-paper oriented.

I hope that is at least some help.

[1] http://wlug.org.nz/PdfLatexNotes
[2] http://www.molspaces.com/d_cb2bib-metadata.php

Comment: Continuing the quest, I discovered another SO question that is somewhat related (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813427/extracting-information-from-pdfs-of-research-papers) which links to a tool called *pdfssa4met* (https://code.google.com/p/pdfssa4met/) which seems promising.